# Drupal 6: restricting a role to create articles to specific categories

Tags: drupal, permissions, roles, taxonomy

Suppose i have the following hierarchy:

- Term1

  - Term11
  - Term12
- Term2

  - Term21
  - Term22

Now i want to allow some roles to be the moderators of articles only in Term11, other roles in Term12 etc.
It's easy when allowing them to update/delete, since i use Taxonomy Access Control module. But when i want to allow role to create articles it's not so easy because on an article creation page i can select any category. But i want to show only that categories in which a role can create articles.

is it possible to do?

Comment: Maybe different taxonomies would be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Taxonomy Term Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/term_permissions) which "allows taxonomy administrators the ability to restrict setting individual terms on nodes by user or role". I don't know if it prevents the display of the taxonomy terms in a list (if it doesn't, that sounds like a good feature request), though it seems to at least disallow setting of certain terms on a node.